# center input box with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

How do I center the input box between the two spans?

```html
<div style="margin: 10% auto 0px; width: 80%;">
   <span style="float: left;">Number of Todos:</span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="input todo" style="text-align: center;">
   <span style="float: right;">Number Checked</span>
</div>
```

Comment: div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add text align to main div. It'll works

```html
<div style="margin: 10% auto 0px; width: 80%; text-align:center;">
   <span style="float: left;">Number of Todos:</span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="input todo" style="text-align: left;">
   <span style="float: right;">Number Checked</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting text-align on parent/containers sets the child elements to be centered,

Reason : the child content is treated as text ,

Once I read a very nice article on this topic. Will find the link n share.

One related article is : https://medium.com/@AmJustSam/is-that-how-you-center-in-css-672dd21a4d60

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest solutions would be to not use `float` and use `display:flex` on the container element instead and then just add `margin:auto` on the left and right of the `<input>` to push the spans to the sides.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;/*top right bottom left*/
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 10% auto 0px; width: 80%;">
  <span>Number of Todos:</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input todo" style="text-align: center;">
  <span>Number Checked</span>
</div>
```